# Can't get Roles using Keyclok with Jakarta EE application

Tags: jakarta-ee, keycloak, openid-connect, payara

I am trying to secure a Jakarta EE application with **keyclok 19.2**
The application server is **payara 5.2023.3**
Everything is under **java 17**

Here is my configuration:

**SecurityBean.class**

```
@OpenIdAuthenticationDefinition(
        providerURI = "http://localhost:8180/realms/myrealm",
        clientId = "test-client",
        clientSecret = "the secret"
)
public class SecurityBean {
}
```

**JakartaRestConfiguration.class**

```
@ApplicationPath("resources")
@DeclareRoles({"test-role"})
public class JakartaRestConfiguration extends Application {
    
}
```

**JakartaEE8Resource.class**

```
@RolesAllowed("test-role")
@Path("rest")
public class JakartaEE8Resource {

    @GET
    public Response ping() {
        return Response
                .ok("ping")
                .build();
    }
}
```

**@WebServlet("/Callback")**

```
@WebServlet("/Callback")
public class Callback extends HttpServlet {

@Inject
    private SecurityContext securityContext;

@Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("caller name: " + context.getCallerName());
        System.out.println("caller groups: " + context.getCallerGroups());
        System.out.println("isCallerInRole? test-role: " + securityContext.isCallerInRole("test-role"));
        response.sendRedirect(
                request.getSession().getAttribute(OpenIdConstant.ORIGINAL_REQUEST).toString()
        );
    }
}
```

The process works well: when I try to reach http://localhost:8080/securityoidc/resources/rest, the request is redirected to keyclok login page where I can successfully login:
`context.getCallerName()` and `context.getCallerGroups()` get the right data.

The test-role is also available in the token

```
"realm_access": {
    "roles": [
      **"test-role",**
      "offline_access",
      "default-roles-syndipro",
      "uma_authorization"
    ]
  }
```

But `isCallerInRole` always returns false, and so when I call http://localhost:8080/securityoidc/resources/rest, the response (after successful login) is always 403.

Did I miss something regarding mapping roles from keycloak to the App?